# Modify Theme Colors/Font Weight

Tags: fonts, themes

As seen below, special words such as functions, types... are rendered with bold font. But the remaining part of the code is not bold. I want to change this behavior.

[image: Ugly bold highlight]

How can I do this? Any idea?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you try `customize-face`?

Comment: I tried (set-face-attribute font-lock-type-face :weight "normal") but it seems to be not working.

Comment: `(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-type-face nil :weight 'normal)`

Comment: Thank you @MathieuMarques `(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-keyword-face nil :weight 'normal)` worked perfectly. I had to change from "normal" to 'normal. I put this statement into `user-config()` section in config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing a parameter when calling `set-face-attribute`. Also, the value for weight is a symbol and not a string.

```el
(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-type-face nil :weight 'normal)
```

Here is a list of the `font-lock` faces: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces-for-Font-Lock.html.

However, if you simply want to un-boldify everything try the following.

```el
(mapc
   (lambda (face)
     (when (eq (face-attribute face :weight) 'bold)
       (set-face-attribute face nil :weight 'normal)))
   (face-list))
```